# Producing an HttpWebRequest ? An ArgumentException Error Occurs

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, http-post

I am trying to post data to `closure-compiler.appspot.com` by using its request header.

This is the request header of application.

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-9,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Content-Length: 269
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: closure-compiler.appspot.com
Origin: null
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko)       Chrome/14.0.794.0 Safari/535.1
```

Thats what I did to create this request in .NET

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/compile");
req.Connection = "keep-alive";
req.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
req.Headers.Add("Origin","null");
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.794.0 Safari/535.1";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
req.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", " ISO-8859-9,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
req.Method = "POST";

Stream reqStr = req.GetRequestStream(); 
//this line give me an argumentexception 
//Keep-Alive and Close may not be set using this property.
//Parameter name: value
```

So how can I produce the header which the application wants me to send ?

Comment: @Bans, You can't set all headers like that using text - some of them require you to use properties specifically for the purpose. Go read the MSDN documentation on `HttpWebRequest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read [THIS](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial1.html) correctly you only need to set the ContentType, so try to do only the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MemoryStream wStr = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(wStr, Encoding.Default);
    writer.Write("js_code=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("alert('hello');// This comment should be stripped"));
    writer.Write("&compilation_level=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("WHITESPACE_ONLY"));
    writer.Write("&output_format=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("text"));
    writer.Write("&output_info=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("compiled_code"));
    writer.Flush();

    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/compile");
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentLength = wStr.Length;

    Stream reqStr = req.GetRequestStream();
    reqStr.Write(wStr.ToArray(), 0, (int)wStr.Length);

    WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
    Stream response = res.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response, Encoding.Default);

    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

It only worked for me with the correct order (req.ContentLength needs to be set before writing) and encoding!

Comment: It says:

'reqStr.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

'reqStr.Position' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

Thanks for reply

Comment: Where do you acces reqStr.Length?

Comment: Stream reqStr = req.GetRequestStream();  This part throws me that exception

Answer (score 2):

How about using a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx). It will make your code much more readable and in addition to this you don't need to struggle with properly URL encoding your parameters, closing streams around, ...:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var values = new NameValueCollection
            {
                { "js_code", "var a = function(arg) { alert(arg); }; a('abc');" },
                { "compilation_level", "ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS" },
                { "output_format", "text" },
                { "output_info", "compiled_code" },
            };
            var url = "http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/compile";
            var result = client.UploadValues(url, values);
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result));
            // outputs 'alert("abc");' on the screen
        }
    }
}
```